# Move a folder in linux

Tags: linux, putty

Currently, I have set this following command:

```
cp symfony-original /db/web/symfonyprojects/job/
```

After this, an error occurred saying that

> cp: omitting directory 'symfony-original'

What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use -r option

```
cp -r symfony-original /db/web/symfonyprojects/job/
```

**cp** is for copying a single file. So it is saying omitting. In case of copying a directory you need to use **-r** option to copy recursively.

Use below command for exploring more options

```
man cp
```

Comment: If I follow your command, this is the output 'cp: cannot create directory `/db/web/symfonyprojects/job/symfony-original': Permission denied'

Comment: I want to copy the folder symfony-original to the job folder

Comment: Is it debian or rpm based?

Comment: try sudo cp -r symfony-original /db/web/symfonyprojects/job/

Answer (score 0):

I'd generally use

```
cp -xa source /destination/path/
```

The -x switch tells cp not to cross filesystem boundaries (in case you have mounted file systems in that path that you don't want to copy as well)

The -a switch is "archive" mode, which effectively does "-d -R --preserve=all" ... the "-d" switch will tell it to copy symlinks, but not traverse them. The "-R' switch is interchangable with the the "-r" switch that user2486495 told you about in their answer.

The "--preserve=all" switch is the magic, in my opinion, as it will attempt to preserve all attributes about the files/folders being copied such as owner, timestamps, mode of the file, etc..